# Default value for text in SimpleContent of XSD

Tags: xsd, schema, default, xsd-1.1

I'm trying to specify an element that extends a simple type (say `xs:string`) with an optional attribute in XSD 1.1. If the element's content/text is empty, I want it to take a default value instead. My current draft is

```xml
<xs:element name="pose" default="0 0 0 0 0 0">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute name="relative_to" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

What I expect is that `<pose></pose>` should become `<pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>` and similarly, `<pose relative-to="something" />` should become `<pose relative-to="something">0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>`

Is this the correct way to do so?

I'm asking, because I'm trying to generate data-bindings from this XSD (using [xsData](https://xsdata.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) and the generated bindings don't pick up the default I specified in `xs:element`. I assume this is due to me misspecifying the schema.

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong with your schema. Have you tried this without the relative-to attribute? Or using an alternative XML processor?

Comment: @kimbert Actually, I think it is a bug in xsData. The example above produces the expected bindings if the element is a child of `<xs:Schema>`, but if it is nested in another element (in my case `<xs:all>`) it stops working.